# Should I use "-ansi" or explicit "-std=..." as compiler flags?

Tags: c, c89, compiler-flags, ansi-c

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232099/are-there-any-differences-between-ansi-c-and-iso-c) that ANSI C is not exactly the same as ISO C and compilers may differ in interpretation of what "-ansi" is about. (gcc maps it to C90, clang maps it to C89) At the moment I would tend to use "-std=..." over "-ansi" as then it is explicitly shown which standard is used. As I am specifically interested in compiling on Linux, Windows and MAC, I fear some compilers could not understand "-std=..." but "-ansi". So are there any pros and cons for using the one over the other?

Comment: I'm not sure you can really expect to build with the exact same flags on three platforms (with different compilers?).

Comment: I don't really expect it, but I want to have platform depended adjustments as small as possible, hence I wanted to know how likely it is that other compilers share those gcc flags too. Now I am warned that this is really gcc specific (I didn't knew that).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want the compiler to enforce the 1989 ANSI C standard, or equivalently the 1990 ISO C standard (they describe exactly the same language), you can safely use either `-ansi` or `-std=c89`.

The name `-ansi` is, strictly speaking, incorrect; it refers to the 1989 ANSI C standard, but ANSI itself considers that standard to be obsolete; it was replaced by the 1999 ISO C standard (which ANSI officially adopted shortly after it was released) which itself either has been, or soon will be, replaced by the new 2011 ISO C standard.  But changing the meaning of the `-ansi` option would break too many `Makefile`s and build scripts.

The gcc 4.7 and later versions also recognize `-std=c90` as a synonym for `-std=c89`.  gcc 4.7 was released in March 2012, so `-std=c90` is reasonably portable unless you need to allow for older versions of gcc.

`-std=c99` enforces (most of) the 1999 ISO C standard.  Since Microsoft in particular doesn't support C99 (even after all these years), using this option means the compiler won't warn you about use of C99-specific features that might not be supported elsewhere. gcc's C99 support is [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C99Status).

gcc 4.7 has *partial* support for the new ISO C 2011 standard, with `-std=c11`. That support has improved in later releases, but is not yet complete. gcc C11 status is [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status), and is said to be similar to the level of C99 support.

There are more options, and a number of aliases for the ones I've mentioned; for example, the option `-std=c9x` was added before the 1999 ISO standard was finalized, and it's still supported; similarly, `-std=c1x` is a synonym for `-std=c11`.

I believe that clang is intended to be as compatible as possible with gcc, so it should support the same options with the same meanings (except perhaps for some of the newer ones, depending on which versions of gcc and clang you're using).

The gcc manual has the full details, with [one section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) describing the supported standards and [another](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) specifying the various `-ansi` and `-std=...` options.  The links are to the 4.7 version.  You can also run `info gcc` (if you have the GNU `info` command and the gcc documentation installed), or you can see multiple versions of the manual [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).

If you're going to use compilers other than gcc (and compilers that aim to be gcc-compatible), you'll have to read their documentation to find out how to enforce various versions of the C standard.

Comment: "even after all these years" - as far as I'm aware, Microsoft officially considers C on Windows to be a dead end. It doesn't and never will attempt to support any version beyond C89, although it has cherry-picked a few features.

Answer (score 4):

`-ansi` and `-std=` compiler flags may be shared by other compilers but they are `gcc` flags.

As of now `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c89` in `gcc` but this may<sup>1)</sup> change in the future so I suggest you to use `-std=c89` over `-ansi`. Indeed ISO c99 for example has also been ratified by ANSI.

You should note that c89 and c90 are essentially the same C Standard. c89 is the ANSI name while c90 is the ISO name.

From `gcc` [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html):

> There were no technical differences between these publications, although the sections of the ANSI standard were renumbered and became clauses in the ISO standard. This standard, in both its forms, is commonly known as C89, or occasionally as C90, from the dates of ratification.

---

1) As noted by Keith Thompson in the comments, even though it's probably unlikely as it would break many  build scripts.

Comment: I would go for `-std=c99` if your compiler supports it (i.e. anything but Microsoft) because C99 has one or two nice things in it that aren't in C89.

Comment: What makes you say that the meaning of `-ansi` might change in the future?  Of course it's possible (it's software after all), but I'd guess that it's about as likely as the meaning of `-std=iso9899:1990` changing.

Comment: It's vanishingly unlikely that `-ansi` will ever refer to anything other than the C89/C90 standard.  Such a change would break too many build scripts and Makefiles.  Using the name "ANSI C" to refer to the 1989 standard is strictly incorrect (ANSI has adopted, or very soon will adopt, the 2011 ISO standard), but the name is too strongly entrenched.